# SSIS OLE DB Destination Truncating Column Data

Tags: sql-server, file-upload, ssis

I'm loading data from a flatfile TXT to a SQL table in SSIS, with a Data Conversion step in between.

In my data conversion I can see my column property before the load is string(DT_STR) with a length of 100. Likewise, in my SQL table design view, my data type is Varchar(100).

My problem is when I perform the data flow task of loading into SQL from the Flatfile, it truncates the data from my flat file and only loads 50 characters instead of the full string. How can I resolve this in SSIS? Is there an element I'm missing here?

Comment: Check that your reader isn't truncating the field and ignoring the error. SSIS is pretty adamant about erroring if this is the case without specifically ignoring the truncation error.

Comment: Could you provide a little more guidance as far as operations to check this Keith? I'm relatively green with SSIS and still picking up nuances with the program.

Comment: Check Advanced properties of your flat file source. The default is 50, but it will error if you are not ignoring the error.